# Ajax file uploading : Unable to upload ONLY ".docx" file

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

The main problem is that all file are being uploaded **except** ".docx" file.

I am using **var formData = new FormData();** and then i append the files into it.

Even strange thing is that i am not able to get the file in my controllers.
The ajax call doesn't even go to controller. 
If i upload PDF or any other file then it is working fine as it should be.

Neither i get any error in console of the firebug nor any response in the network tab of the firebug tab.
I have set ajax loader on the ajax call and it just keeps loading.
Nothing happens and then i will have to refresh the page.

The ajax call doesn't even reach to the controller function.

Below is my code.

And yes, thank you all the stackoverflow developer for your all earlier support.

There are two documents i am uploading and both could be in any format from the format that are allowed in the function below.

This The **View code**

```
$("#cover-letter").change(function(){ 
         var file = this.files[0];
            name = file.name;
            size = file.size;
            type = file.type;

            var get_ext     =   name.split('.');
            get_ext         =   get_ext.reverse();

            if (get_ext[0].toLowerCase() == 'wps' || get_ext[0].toLowerCase() == 'doc' || get_ext[0].toLowerCase() == 'docx' || get_ext[0].toLowerCase() == 'pdf'){
                $('#img_error').hide();
                readURL(this);
            } else {
                $('#img_error').show();
                $('#img_error').css('color','red'); 
                $('#img_error').text("Invalide file format");
                $("#cvr_name").text('Attach Cover Letter');
                $(this).val('');
                $('#img_name').empty();

            } 
    });

    $("#resume").change(function(){

         var file       = this.files[0];
            name        = file.name;
            size        = file.size;
            type        = file.type;

            var get_exts    =   name.split('.');
            get_exts        =   get_exts.reverse();

            if ( get_exts[0].toLowerCase() == 'wps' || get_exts[0].toLowerCase() == 'doc' || get_exts[0].toLowerCase() == 'docx' || get_exts[0].toLowerCase() == 'pdf' ){
                $('#resume_error').hide();
                readDocsURL(this);
            } else {
                $('#resume_error').show();
                $('#resume_error').css('color','red');  
                $('#resume_error').text("Invalide file format");
                $("#res_val").text('Attach Resume');
                $(this).val('');
                // $('#resume_error').attr("disabled", true);
                $('#res_name').empty();


            } 

    });

            // image name
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                // $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                var remove = '<img id="cross-remove" class="cross-remove" src="'+IMAGE_URL+'cross-remove.png">';
                var imgpath = $("#cover-letter").val();
                if(imgpath != '') {
                    document.getElementById("img_name").textContent = imgpath;
                    $("#img_name").append(remove);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("img_name").textContent = '';
                }
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    // resume or docs url
    function readDocsURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                // $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                var remove = '<img id="cross-remove" class="cross-remove" src="'+IMAGE_URL+'cross-remove.png">';
                var respath = $("#resume").val();
                if(respath != '') {
                    document.getElementById("res_name").textContent = respath;
                    $("#res_name").append(remove);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("res_name").textContent = '';
                }
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $('.addimages').click(function(e) {

        $("#validateForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                $("#loading").css("display","block");
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append( 'coverletter', $( '#cover-letter' )[0].files[0] );
                formData.append( 'resume', $('#resume')[0].files[0] );
                formData.append( 'comment', $( '#comment' ).val() );            
                formData.append( 'iAdvertiseID', $( '#iAdvertiseID' ).val() );                      
                console.log($( '#cover-letter' )[0].files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('application_form/do_upload'); ?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data){
                        "<?php unset($_POST); ?>";
                        $('#res_name').empty();
                        $('#img_name').empty();
                        $("#validateForm").get(0).reset();
                        var msg = "<div id='alert'><div class='messege widthinherit martop10 messege-info'>"+data+"</div></div>";
                        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
                        $("#loading").css("display","none");
                        $("#appendme").html(msg).fadeOut(3000);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller Code**

```
$iApplicationID = $this->application_form_model->addApplication();
            $emailInfo = $this->application_form_model->getEmailInfo($_POST['iAdvertiseID']);
            if(isset($_FILES['coverletter']['name'])) {

                /*$imgid        =  explode ('.', $_FILES['coverletter']['name']);

                $checktype = in_array($imgid[1],  array('docx', 'doc', 'wps', 'word', 'pdf'));*/

                // if($checktype == 1) {

                    $coverPath = DOC_ROOT.'/uploads/cover/'.'advertise_'.$_POST['iAdvertiseID'].'/'.$this->userID.'/';

                    if (!is_dir($coverPath)) {
                        if (!mkdir($coverPath, 0777, TRUE)) {
                            exit('dir not created.');
                        }
                    }

                    $config['upload_path']          =   $coverPath;
                    $config['allowed_types']        =   '*';
                    /*$config['max_size']             =   '10000';
                    $config['max_width']            =   '2000';
                    $config['max_height']           =   '2000';*/
                    $config['encrypt_name']         =   FALSE;

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('coverletter')) {

                            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                            $this->load->view('application_form/application_form_view', $error);

                     } else { 

                            $data             =   array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                            $img_file_path  =   $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                            $this->db->update('tbl_application', array('vCoverLetter' => $img_file_path), array('iApplicationID' => $iApplicationID));              
                     }
                // } else {
                //      echo "Different File formate";  
                // }
            }
            if(isset($_FILES['resume']['name'])) {

                /*$resid        =  explode ('.', $_FILES['resume']['name']);

                $checktype = in_array($resid[1],  array('docx', 'doc','wps','word','pdf'));*/

                // if($checktype == 1) {

                    $resumePath = DOC_ROOT.'/uploads/resume/'.'advertise_'.$_POST['iAdvertiseID'].'/'.$this->userID.'/';

                    if (!is_dir($resumePath)) {
                        if (!mkdir($resumePath, 0777, TRUE)) {
                            exit('dir not created.');
                        }
                    }

                    $config['upload_path']          =   $resumePath;
                    $config['allowed_types']        =   '*';
                    /*$config['max_size']             =   '10000';
                    $config['max_width']            =   '2000';
                    $config['max_height']           =   '2000';*/
                    $config['encrypt_name']         =   FALSE;

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('resume')) {

                            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                            $this->load->view('application_form/application_form_view', $error);

                    } else { 

                            $data               =       array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                            $file_file_path   = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                            $this->db->update('tbl_application', array('vResume' => $file_file_path), array('iApplicationID' => $iApplicationID));
                           // $this->thumbimg($data['upload_data']['full_path'], $data['upload_data']['file_name'], '0');   
                     }
                /*} else {
                    echo "Different File formate";  
                }*/
            }
```

Comment: where is you controller upload code?

Comment: There is the controller code right below view code. Just added.

Comment: 'docx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip') check this line in application/config/mime.php

Comment: MIME type is already set as above.. @sanirranta